# Client unable to access OWA website after temporarily changing SSL certificate on the server

Tags: browser, ssl, ssl-certificate, outlook-web-access

I have the following issue:

One client computer (Windows XP) cannot access the OWA website. All other client computers can (Except another one in the same remote office).

How this happened: I temporarily changed the SSL certificate on the Exchange Server yesterday. After a few minutes, I reverted back, an now the same certificate that was installed for years is back again. During these few minutes, they were in OWA on this computer and got a certificate error.

What exactly happens: Internet Explorer displays the error `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage`, Firefox displays `The connection was reset` and Crome shows `This webpage is not available. The connection to ... was interrupted`.

What I already did to try to get this working:

- Restart the client computer
- Restart the exchange server
- Deleted Internet Explorer browsing history
- In IE, *Internet Options*, tab *Content*, under *Certificates* deletes SSL cache
- Restored Internet Explorer to the default parameters
- I looked into certmgr.msc, but did not find a certificate related to the issue

What could I do else to narrow down the origin of this problem (or better: resolve it) ? Can you give any advice ?

Comment: Does it matter who you've logged into Windows as?  Like does it behave the same way for any/all users who log into the problematic computer(s)? What is the actual web reply code/error being returned (404, 503, etc.)? If you access it by IP instead of computer name does it behave any differently? you ay it's a "remote office", how are they connected to the Exchange server? LAN, VPN, Internet? Are all these machine on a domain? If so, is it the SAME domain? :)

Comment: The URL is https://mail.sbgmb.net. If you see the login screen you don't have the problem.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 To answer all your questions: I created a new user, this account has the same problem. There is no http reply code, the browsers show the error messages reported above. No, I cannot access the site by IP neither. They connect to the exchange server through OWA (Outlook Web Access), that is a public webmail interface. No those client machines are not joined to the domain, they're in a Workgroup.

Comment: You may have to use the browsers' developer tools to find the actual code.  If there's NO reply, then it sounds like you have connectivity issues that have little/nothing to do with the certificate.  Can you communicate with the server at ALL from the problematic client?  IE: Can you ping the server? By name? By IP?  Does a tracert make it all the way to the server?  Are there any computers in the "remote office" that _can_ access it?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, you're right. The client's IP got blacklisted for too many failed login attempts. To bad, I lost too much time on this problem. And thanks for your help that was crucial !

Comment: Good to hear!  I posted an answer reflecting this discovery if you'd like to accept it.  PS: Please don't edit your question to include "Solved" (or the chosen solution), that's not how we roll here on SU. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can access the OWA interface via the URL you supplied, so that end is working fine.

There may be a connectivity problem (downed VPN, incorrect routing, blocked IP address, etc.) between the remote office and the HQ where the Exchange server is.

If *none* of the computers in the remote office can get to the web UI, then ensure you can actually contact the Exchange server from the remote office.

`Ping` and `Tracert` are your friends to start determining if and where the blockage is.